# SVG Четкий контроль тайминга анимации передвижения?

Tags: svg, анимация, svg-animation, smil

Подскажите, можно ли добиться в SVG чёткого контроля времени анимирования при анимации перемещения. Приведу простой пример

```css
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">

  <defs>
    <path class="myPath" d="M0,0 34.4,-36 70.7,0 35.4,35.4 0,0" id="Left_path1"></path>
  </defs>

  <path class="rec b1" transform="rotate(-45 30 100)" d="M9.3 80h40v40h-40z">
    <animateMotion dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#Left_path1"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>

</svg>
```

Есть некий объект () перемещающийся по траектории (class="myPath") состоящей  из 5 ключевых точек. Анимация длиться 4с и повторяется бесконечно(это важно). Вопрос - как сделать так что б из точки пути myPath 0.0 -> 34.4,-36 квадрат двигался 1с потом ожидал в этой точки 500ms потом из 34.4,-36 -> 70.7,0 проскакивал за 500ms потом снова ожидал 500ms , потом передвигался в позицию 35.4,35.4 за 1s и потом возвращался в начальное положение за ту же 1с. Время перемещений взято от балды, хотелось бы разобраться в принципе возможно ли контролировать с точностью до 100ms? 
*Пробовал переписать анимацию через параметры values и keyTimes но не получилось + там больше % отношение, а для меня важна точность. В тех "стоянках" с объектом будут взаимодействовать другие объекты SVG и может получиться разсинхрон по timeline

Comment: сумма времен которые Вы указали - 4.5 сек, но в целом сейчас я отвечу как этим управлять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для управления анимацией используются значение 2х параметров

```
keyTimes=  "0 ; 0.250 ; 0.375 ; 0.50 ; 0.675 ; 1 "
keyPoints= "0 ; 0.250 ; 0.250 ; 0.50 ; 0.500 ; 1 "
```

первый определяет точки на временной оси, второй - на пути, по которому движется объект, оба значения находятся в интервале от 0 до 1, от реальной продолжительности - придется пересчитать в проценты =)

так же необходимо задать

```
calcMode="linear"
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <path class="myPath" d="M0,0 34.4,-36 70.7,0 35.4,35.4 0,0" id="Left_path1"></path>
  </defs>
  <path class="rec b1" transform="rotate(-45 30 100)" d="M9.3 80h40v40h-40z">
    <animateMotion dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"
    
                calcMode="linear"
                keyTimes=  "0 ; 0.250 ; 0.375 ; 0.50 ; 0.675 ; 1 "
                keyPoints= "0 ; 0.250 ; 0.250 ; 0.50 ; 0.50 ; 1 "         
    >
      <mpath xlink:href="#Left_path1"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Круто, а можно объяснить, как были получены значения для   keyTimes и keyPoints ? (Особенно keyPoints) ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 эм, вообще их можно посчитать для вашего случая достаточно легко, вся длина поделена на 4, это 1/4 или 0.25 - длина одной стороны. А вообще есть метод pointAtLength и getTotalLength, при помощи которых можно достаточно точные значения получить